# Fabricjs: How to get the area?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I need to know the area of all elements of the group. Is there a ready-made solution? Perhaps you know the area excluding the imposition?

```
window.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabriccanvas');
var circle1 = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 50,
  fill: 'red',
  left: 0
});
var Rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 50,
  top: 50,
  height: 20,
  width: 20,
  fill: 'green'
});
var circle2 = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 20,
  fill: 'black',
  left: 70,
  top: 80
});
var group = new fabric.Group([ circle1, circle2, Rect ], {});
window.canvas.add(group);
```

Comment: you can get area of full canvas , area of each object

Answer (score 0):

VINET,

There is no predefined functionality, you have to build your own. This is short example how to calculate area for circles and rectangles in the group (as you created above):

```
var groupArea = 0;

group.forEachObject(function(o){
  groupArea += calculateArea(o);
});

function calculateArea(obj){
    switch (obj.type){
    case 'circle':
        return Math.PI*obj.radius*obj.radius;
    break;
    case 'rect':
        return obj.width*obj.height;
    break;
  }
}

alert(groupArea);
```

This post is how to calculate polygon area: [Calculating Polygon Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285134/calculating-polygon-area)

This post is for triangle area: [Calculate triangle area and circumference from user input sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329172/calculate-triangle-area-and-circumference-from-user-input-sides)

Hopefully it will help you.